# Android app storing client certificates in a secure and proper way

Tags: java, android, authentication, kotlin, client-certificates

I am building an Android application that will need Certificate based authentication. I'm not so familiar with Java/Kotlin programming paradigms.

The certificates will be issued one of two ways, via an API (which I control) or via a Device Management tool such as MobiControl (this is the only one, currently, but we may have to use other device management tools).

I need a way to store the certificates securely, but in a way that we can deploy them automatically using a Device Management suite and they will persist indefinitely. Is the certificate store sufficient? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/CertStore

In unix, I'd store them in `/etc/ssl/certs` but I don't know if this is a valid Android approach.

Comment: So if I get it right, the first way to instal a client certificate is using an MDM like MobiControl. The second way is the app you develop. Should the client certificate be used by multiple apps (e.g. web browser, or other third party apps) or just by the app you develop?

Comment: Just by this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an app want's to store a client certificate that is only used by this app I strongly recommend to use the [`AndroidKeyStore` system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). See also [this blog entry](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/keystore-redesign-in-android-m.html).

If the device supports the private key is stored encrypted and can't be accessed by apps (only used). Event the app itself can't extract the private key, however it can use the private key for e.g. signing or decrypting data using a java `Cipher` instance.

Furthermore you can set by just one flag that using the certificate requires an device authentication (e.g. via fingerprint) before the app can use it.

Comment: How should the import from MDM tools work? Can they import the certificate directly into the keystore?

Comment: Well that is up to the developer of the MDM solution and therefore not your concern. Anyway you have to use the method provided by the MDM (if there is one provided). One can even think of a special interface in the MDM app which allows to use the certificate by other apps.